# Mysql + php : select count group by day and user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i have the tables below

```
       USER                      COMMENT
---------------------     -----------------------
 |   id   |   name         | id | user_id | date
---------------------     -----------------------
 |   1    |     joe        | 1  |    1    | 2014-10-10
 |   2    |     jane       | 1  |    1    | 2014-10-10
 |   3    |     ted        | 1  |    3    | 2014-10-11
```

My aim is to create a stats comparaison chart. So i want to extract for each current week days, the number of comment added by each user.
The expected array

```
-----------------------------
            2014-10-10
-----------------------------
joe  |  2
jane |  0
ted  |  0
------------------------------
            2014-10-11
------------------------------
joe  |  0
jane |  0
ted  |  1
```

I did a simple left join query and double group by, but the result was not formatted like expected.

Maybe, i have to sort and merge results using php?!

Thank you for the help

Comment: Your expected results don't match your data.  Should Joe not have 2 comments on 10/10?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i'll fix that. (edited)

Comment: Formatting like this isn't MySQLs job. You will get that sorted with `ORDER BY date DESC, COUNT(*) DESC, id ASC`. While looping through your result, you've only watch the change in the date column.

Comment: Comment has no PRIMARY KEY. This is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT c1.date, c1.name, COUNT(c2.date)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT c.date, u.name, u.id
    FROM COMMENT c
    CROSS JOIN USER u) c1
LEFT JOIN COMMENT c2
ON c1.id = c2.user_id AND c1.date = c2.date
GROUP BY c1.date, c1.id
```

The difficulty was to obtain a list of all users for each date, which I produced with the sub query `c1`.

Comment: Note: possibly a typo - `u.I'd` should be `u.id`? :-)

Comment: @Darren, Yes thanks! spelling autocorrect keeps bugging me whenever I write `id`; this one escaped me.

Comment: Perfectly alright, that's what we are all here for!

Comment: @Darren No higher purpose? :-(

Comment: @Strawberry In your case, it's being delicious!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is

```
Select User.name , Comment.date
From Comment Left Join User On Comment.user_id = User.id
Order By Comment.date Desc
```

This would return a list with user who commented + date.

Now I would parse the result set :-

```
$query = "query above";
$rowset = $db->fetchAll($query);

$result = array();
foreach ($rowset as $row) {
    $result[$row['date']][$row[User]] += 1
}
```

This would give you an array

```
Date1
    =>user1
      =>count
    =>user2
      =>count
Date2
    =>user3
      =>count
    =>user4
      =>count
```

Comment: That's the php way: notice that you need to return the score for every users and every day! You should be able to retrieve the list of users with a first query.